# Terminal won't let me print pointer to string without newline character at end - C

Tags: c, string, memory, io, output

So as the title says I have a pointer to a string, but it won't let me print it out without printing a newline at the end.

Here is what I have:

```
char *rcv_message = malloc(msg_len); /* where msg_len = 5, because input is "hello" we are not supposed to worry about the null terminator */

printf("%s", rcv_message);
```

Without the new line, print line doesn't print anything. The terminal is just blank.

But when I add a new line at the end, like:

```
printf("%s\n", rcv_message);
```

It prints out the message.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is going wrong. The output is 'line buffered' by default, meaning the output won't be sent to the terminal until you write a newline, or force it out with `fflush()`, or (on many systems) start an input operation on standard input.

Incidentally, if you're not going to worry about the null terminator, then you need to limit the printing with:

```
printf("%.5s", rcv_message);
```

But you should think carefully about it.  Adding a null to the allocated string writes outside the bounds of the array.  That's undefined behaviour, and undefined behaviour is unconditionally bad — to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Well the number of bytes for rcv_message is always going to be strlen(message); where message is whatever message is put into the command line argument. So in this case for "hello", rcv_message is 5 bytes, not 6 because we are excluding the null byte at the end.

Comment: So in that case, what do you mean by "Incidentally, if you're not going to worry about the null terminator, then you need to limit the printing with: printf("%.5s", rcv_message);" Why should I need the .5?

Comment: How else is printf() going to know how many chars to print? With no length and no terminator, you gonna have UB.

Comment: If `rcv_message` holds 5 bytes and is not null terminated, you can't print it with plain `%s` because that only works (reliably) with mill-terminated strings. You could use `%.*s` and provide the length as an argument to `printf()`. That would not limit you to 5-character strings.